# Is it possible to obtain an electronic copy of a UK visa decision letter?

Tags: visas, uk, student-visas

I have been granted a student visa for the UK. A vignette sticker in my passport and a decision letter from the UK Home Office have been received.

Is the decision letter, which must be presented to an immigration officer upon arriving in the UK, available in an electronic PDF version, possibly through a visa application portal? I don't want a photocopy; I only want a backup copy to have on hand in case.

Comment: I’ve never seen any references to the availability of decision letters online. If it’s just for backup, would scanning the original letter to your phone or laptop be sufficient?

Comment: The passport sticker itself could only be photocopied. I take copies of documents with me (stored in a different place) 'just in case' but I have never needed them.

Answer (score 5):

This question has a false premise: it is not necessary to present your decision letter at the border.

However, it is possible nonetheless to get a copy of the decision letter for any UK visa application. You should make a 'specific' [subject access request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration) to the Home Office.

If you have a physical copy of the decision letter already, scanning it will be much easier and faster than making this request, which may take weeks or even months to process.